# .getTime is not a function

Tags: javascript, date, parse-platform

So I am having a problem with comparing two dates. Today is stored as 2016-04-17 and date is stored as the same just with minutes and seconds behind the date. today.getTime() doesn't seem to work even though I have stored today as a date. Appreciate the help.

```
function getAnswers() {
                var Query = new Parse.Query(Surveys);
                Query.include("survey");
                var today = new Date().toJSON().slice(0, 10);

                Query.find({
                        success: function(objects, results) {

                            for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
                                var navn = objects[i].get("survey").get("name");
                                if (navn == "Trening") {
                                    var query = new Parse.Query(SurveyAnswer);
                                    query.descending("createdAt");
                                    query.include("author");
                                    query.equalTo("survey", objects[i]);
                                    query.find({
                                            success: function(results) {

                                                for (var i in results) {
                                                    var date = results[i].get("createdAt");
                                                    console.log(date.getTime());

                                                    console.log(today.getTime());
                                                    if (date.getTime() === today.getTime()) {
                                                        console.log("Yay");
                                                    } else {
                                                        console.log("This didn't work");
                                                    }


                                                }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert date to a Date object.

```
var date = new Date(results[i].get("createdAt"));
```

Comment: date is already a Date object. I am using Parse and the results I am getting out is stored as a Date. It is today which is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

var today = new Date().toJSON().slice(0, 10); --> after this, today is no longer a date object, it becomes a string which no longer has the getTime function.

Comment: Any idea how I can get it to a Date again?

Comment: Don't turn it into a string in the first place. BTW,  `new Date().toJSON()` is identical to `new Date().toISOString()`, the latter is more semantic. Note also that this will be the equivalent GMT date, so may be different to your local (i.e. host system) date.